# Nested Criteria/Filters in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Could anyone give me some idea on how I can select/update records in Access based on the data and criteria below?

Background: `Headcount=1` should be set for all records except to those with duplicate records/roles (by `ApptID`). For those `count(Headcount)>1`, I have to set `Headcount=0` for the record with:

1. `Right(Empcode,5)<>Right(ApptID,5)` and Fixed i.e. `100005-300678`
2. If both Cont, just the `Right(Empcode,5)<>Right(ApptID,5)` record i.e. `100006-300583`
3. If 2 similar `APPTID` records does not contain an empcode that has 5 digits similar with `ApptID` (i.e. `100007`), and both are fixed or cont, whichever has the lowest FTE per will have `Headcount=0` i.e. `100007-300295 / 100008-300419`

```
    APPTID | EmpCode | FTE | Status | HEADCOUNT  

    100001 | 300001  | 1.0 | Cont   | 1  
    100002 | 300002  | 0.9 | Cont   | 1  
    100003 | 300003  | 0.8 | Fixed  | 1  
    100004 | 300004  | 1.0 | Cont   | 1  
    100005 | 300005  | 0.5 | Cont   | 1  
    100005 | 300678  | 0.5 | Fixed  | 1  
    100006 | 300006  | 0.4 | Cont   | 1   
    100006 | 300583  | 0.4 | Cont   | 1  
    100007 | 300295  | 0.4 | Fixed  | 1  
    100007 | 300385  | 0.6 | Fixed  | 1  
    100008 | 300419  | 0.4 | Cont   | 1  
    100008 | 300902  | 0.6 | Cont   | 1
```

Currently creating a select query first before the update query. I have managed to do the first criteria with this:

```
SELECT ApptID, EmpCode, FTE, Status, Headcount
FROM Staff S
WHERE S.ApptID in (
    Select Tmp.ApptID FROM Staff as Tmp 
    Group by Tmp.ApptID 
    Having Sum(Tmp.Headcount)>1)
AND RIGHT(S.ApptID,5)<>RIGHT(S.EmpCode,5)
AND S.Status="Fixed";
```

From here, I don't know how to proceed with the 2nd and 3rd as all of my attempts results to the inclusion of other records.